# How to pass key value pairs as parameters in Route Path?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

The react documentation says that the `match` object contains a `param` property assigned to an object with `Key/value pairs parsed from the URL corresponding to the dynamic segments of the path`.

When I try to pass key value pairs as parameters, I only get the key, but the value is always undefined.

```
<Route path="/location:color?" component={Location} />
```

If I do this, and then in the Location component, I console log props.match, I get the match object, but when I open it, I get this: `params: {color: undefined}`.

How do I pass value too?

Also, I feel like I'm misunderstanding something about these path parameters, because what exactly is the point of them? If I wanted to pass any value to any component, I can just use props. What is the purpose of these path parameters?

Comment: The point is for things like dynamic page URLs. Say `mydomain.com/users/52/edit`. Where you have a `Route` defined as `<Route path="/users/:id" .../>`. Then in your component you know which user to fetch data for by the `id` param.

Comment: @BrianThompson okay.. and what about the value? Why do I only get the key in the Match object? How do I also pass a value for that key?

Answer (score 0):

The idea of using `path="/location/:color?"`:

- is to fetch/navigate to a page according to its id to get information
  For example, I want to get student information on the page, first, it goes to URL `www.location/studentId` it will take the student id to know which student to view on the page.
- In your case, you get `undefined` because you didn't pass any color value, so you need to pass the value to navigate as follow:

  ```
    - change `<Route path="/location:color?" component={Location} />` 
    to `<Route path="/location/:color?" component={Location} />`

    -  To navigate use `this.props.history.replace("/location/" + this.props.color);`
  ```

Please read this article it will give you more ideas about react-routes[react routes Article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-handle-routing-in-react-apps-with-react-router)

or [React routes documentation](https://knowbody.github.io/react-router-docs/)

Comment: Sorry for making you confused, you should first change ` <Route path="/location:color?" component={Location} /> `  to   ` <Route path="/location/:color?" component={Location} /> `  to be defined and I meant by the `this.props.history.replace("/location/" + this.props.color);` to navigate to the page from other page

Answer (score 0):

For all complex data structures, I recommand parsing to string and deserialize at the other end. it may be a good practice if everyone in your team is doing it this way.
Example :

```
KeyValuePair : <Color,Blue> 
Parse it to string : "\"Color\",\"Blue\"
```